# How to set alias field to a multi key Hash in Ruby on Rails plus Mongo Develop Environment

Tags: ruby, mongodb

For instance there is a model called `Order` and in my Mongo Database there has data like this

```
#<Order price: "100", receiver:{"name"=>"Betty", "cell_phone" =>"123"}>
```

my problem is that I don't know how to write an alias in my order.rb file that can get the key "name" in my receiver Hash using sentence like

```
field :money_spent, type:Float, as: :price
```

can someone please tell me if it is feasible?

Comment: What odm are you using? Please provide more specifics as we have no idea what a receiver is or how it is modeled.

Comment: @Tyler Brock Thanks for your attention,I'm using ROR, Order is a decument in MongoDB and receiver is a field in it,if I write order.receiver it should return {"name"=>"Betty", "cell_phone" =>"123"}